# What happens when someone in the US clicks on a GB itunes URL?

Tags: itunes, url

If I provide a GB url itunes link to an app, say

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/id586088546

what would happen if someone in outside the UK, say in the states clicks on that? would it work or would it redirect to a version on their regional app store?

Answer (score 2):

The view from Chicago is below. The prices are in GBP. When I click on the View in iTunes link, the prices change to USD.

Staying in my browser, if I change `gb` to `us` in your original URL, the prices change to USD but everything else seems to stay the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will try to open the app's page on the iTunes Store linked to the account (when opened in iTunes).

For example, for me, it opened the page on the french store.